# Objects keep replacing one and other in Array List?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, field

Im making a Shopping Cart for a java project and I'm having trouble adding multiple objects to my array list.

My array is created in class Basket

```
package store;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.Spring;


public class Basket {

    private double totalPrice;
    public int orderNumber=1;

    private ArrayList<Product> basket = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

In this class i also have the method

```
public ArrayList<Product> getBasket (){
        return basket ;
    }
```

In a seperate class where the user selects what item he wants and hits a button what creates a GolfBag(Sub class of Product Class).

```
GolfBags gb = new GolfBags(1,productType, productPrice, productName, quantity, colour, size);

b.getBasket().add(gb);
System.out.println(b.getBasket());
int counter=b.getBasket().size();
System.out.println(counter);
```

The first time i hit it, It displays the order correctly,however the second time I would expect it to show two of the same item as two objects should of been created and added however the counter displays the number to still be one and the order only appears once. Any help on this would be very grateful.

To the comments about where the basket is created? Isnt it created in the line private ArrayList basket = new ArrayList(); ?

```
addGolfBag.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Basket b = new Basket ();
                int productNumber = 0 ;
                String productName = null ;
                double productPrice = 0 ;
                String productType = "BAG";
                int quantity = 0;
                String colour = null;
                String size = null;

                if (((String) golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem())
                        .equals("TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag")){ 

                    productNumber=b.getOrderNumber();
                    productName="TaylorMade Juggernaut";
                    productPrice=(129*(Integer)golfBagQuanititySpinner.getValue());
                    quantity=(Integer)golfBagQuanititySpinner.getValue();
                    colour="BLUE";
                    size="LARGE";
                }
                if (((String) golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem())
                        .equals("Mizuno Golf Rider Cart Bag")){ 

                    productNumber=b.getOrderNumber();
                    productName="Mizuno Golf Rider";
                    productPrice=(99.99*(Integer)golfBagQuanititySpinner.getValue());
                    quantity=(Integer)golfBagQuanititySpinner.getValue();
                    colour="BLACK";
                    size="SMALL";
                }
                if (((String) golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem())
                        .equals("Titleist RC13 Reverse Cart Bag")){ 

                    productNumber=b.getOrderNumber();
                    productName="Titleist RC13 Reverse";
                    productPrice=(99.99*(Integer)golfBagQuanititySpinner.getValue());
                    quantity=(Integer)golfBagQuanititySpinner.getValue();
                    colour="SILVER";
                    size="LARGE";
                }
                if (((String) golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem())
                        .equals("Callaway Golf Euro Chev Org Cart Bag")){ 

                    productNumber=b.getOrderNumber();
                    productName="Callaway Golf Euro";
                    productPrice=(79*(Integer)golfBagQuanititySpinner.getValue());
                    quantity=(Integer)golfBagQuanititySpinner.getValue();
                    colour="BLUE";
                    size="MEDIUM";
                }

                    GolfBags gb = new GolfBags(1,productType, productPrice, productName, quantity, colour, size);

                    b.getBasket().add(gb);
                    System.out.println(b.getBasket());
                    int counter=b.getBasket().size();
                    System.out.println(counter);


            }});
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code that two adds items to the basket. I strongly suspect you're only creating *one* object, and adding two references to the same object to your list. Either that, or your `GolfBags` code contains static variables. Ideally, show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The bug is in the code you don't show. Show us how and where a Basket is created, and the code calling the method which adds a GolfBags to the basket.

Comment: Is the basket not created in the line private ArrayList<Product> basket = new ArrayList<Product>();

Comment: The object of type Basket: where is it created?

Comment: You're creating a new Basket object each time you click your button.

Comment: The object is created in another class to where the array list is, how can i call the array list to add the object without having to create a new instance of basket?

Comment: How can i have it so the array list can have items added to it without being in the same class and not having to instance of basket?

Answer (score 1):

OK. Now that you posted the code, the error is obvious:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Basket b = new Basket ();
```

So, each time the button is clicked, the `actionPerformed()` method is called. And each time it's called, it creates a new instance of Basket, containing a new `List<Product>`.

The Basket object should probably be a **field** of your UI class, initialized in the constructor, instead of being a local variable of the `actionPerformed()` method..

Side note: you shouldn't expose the list of products to the outside. You should instead have a method `addProduct()` method in the Basket class, that will add the product to the list, AND will add the price of the product to the total price. That's what encapsulation is all about. If you want to user of the class to be able to iterate over the products, then return a read-only view of the list, to prevent him from adding a product behind your back: `return Collections.unmodifiableList(basket)`.

Comment: How would i be able to add the item to the array list without having to create a new instance of the Basket class?

Comment: As I said in my answer: the basket (i.e. the instance of Basket) should be a field of the class, and not a local variable of the `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: How can i make it a field of the class appose to the way i;ve made it here?

Comment: `private Basket basket = new Basket();`. I have the feeling that you don't know the basics of Java and OO yet. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html, or a good introductory book, before using Swing, which is complex, and needs a good understanding of these basics.